# How to Remove installation's base currency from order summary in admin

Tags: magento, admin

Does anyone know a quick way to remove the base currency from the order summary detail from within Magento's admin panel?

For example at the moment on our multi store setup we have order summary displaying like so:

`Grand Total £447.60
           [€523.43]`

We want to display the totals in just the store currency that the order was placed in (in this case €'s)